# Analyze nodejs memory with and without stream API

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, stream, aws-sdk

node v14.17.0

I try to test memory consumption with and without the use of a streams. The main goal is to find a metric that will show clearly the benefits of using stream.

Currently the results look the same:

TEST #1: read file without stream

```
test('read file without stream and upload to s3', async () => {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './benda.js'), 'utf8');
    await _uploadFile(`${FILE_NAME}`, bucket, fileContent);
    const used = process.memoryUsage();
    for (let key in used) {
        console.log(`${key} ${Math.round(used[key] / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100} MB`);
    }
})
```

result #1:

```
    rss 1541.91 MB
    heapTotal 538.3 MB
    heapUsed 535.07 MB
    external 482.39 MB
    arrayBuffers 0.1 MB
```

TEST #2: create read stream and upload to s3

```
test('create read stream and upload to s3', async () => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, './benda.js'));
    await _uploadFile(`${FILE_NAME}`, bucket, readStream);
    const used = process.memoryUsage();
    for (let key in used) {
        console.log(`${key} ${Math.round(used[key] / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100} MB`);
    }
});


const _uploadFile = async(fileName, bucket, streamOrContent) => {
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: fileName,
      Body: streamOrContent
    });
    
    const res:PutObjectCommandOutput = await s3Client.send(command);
    return res;
  };
```

result #2:

```
rss 1543.93 MB
heapTotal 539.8 MB
heapUsed 536.39 MB
external 485.05 MB 
arrayBuffers 3.39 MB
```

It seems pretty the same, the file size is ~504MB

Please let me know what I'm missing here? or my test is wrong?

Comment: Why would you think that reading a file from a local disk is the same operation as uploading a file to s3 and therefore should use the same amount of temporal memory?  These are vastly different code paths, implemented completely differently.  It's a no wonder they might use a different amount of memory to accomplish their job.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated the question by uploading the file to s3 on test #1 too. still getting the same result. Do you have a better use-case to test memory usage?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?  You have measured that two different code paths (one using a stream, the other reading the whole file into memory) happen to use a slightly different amount of memory in one specific test.  This is not surprising in the least.  Is there an actual problem here?  All this memory usage should only be temporal too so as soon as you aren't using those variables any more and the operation is done, the garbage collector will reclaim that memory as available for reuse by future Javascript allocations.

Comment: I'm going to load large amounts of data from different types of databases. My goal is to reduce the load on the servers, and I thought that one of the ways is to use streaming instead of loading huge files into memory

Comment: Streaming loads data in chunks rather than load the whole thing into memory so if all else is equal, streaming may have lower peak memory usage.  But, a 2MB file size is practically noise in these measurements (only 2% of the heap) and may be countered by additional usage by the streaming mechanism.  Try it with a 2GB file and the difference will much more obvious.

Comment: I updated my test to use file size is ~504MB. Still same result. Maybe there is another metric that will show clearly the benefits of using stream?